# Find Unique IDs in SQL from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query that I have to get teacher and student ids

```
Select lk.teacherID,lk.studentID from Teacher a inner join student b 
on a.classkey = b.classkey

Teacher ID   Student ID
123            678
123            876
123            987
456            459
456            789
```

End Results that I am looking for: -
Find Unique IDs in SQL from two columns

```
Unique IDs
123
678
876
987
456
459
789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select lk.teacherID as UniqueIDs 
From(
Select lk.teacherID,lk.studentID from Teacher a inner join student b 
on a.classkey = b.classkey)a
GROUP By teacherID

Union all

Select lk.studentID as UniqueIDs From(
Select lk.teacherID,lk.studentID from Teacher a inner join student b 
on a.classkey = b.classkey)a
GROUP By studentID
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.teacherId
from teachers t
union
select s.studentId
from students s;
```

EDIT:

For the clarification, just use `cross apply`:

```
Select distinct id
from Teacher t inner join
     student s
     on t.classkey = s.classkey cross apply
     (values (t.teacherId), (s.studentId)) v(id);
```

Comment: No I have the query above to find those results first, now out of that result set. I want the end result as mentioned above

Comment: @LearnAspNet . . . I wasn't sure exactly what you meant.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I do not like Cross Apply joins, What is the best way. Other answer that someone added worked but I think that can be performance issue @Gordon

Comment: @LearnAspNet . . . Whether you like `cross apply` or not, lateral joins are an important part of SQL and this should be the best performing approach.

Answer (score 0):

There no need to take more than a single pass over the data.

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp;

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    Teacher_ID int NOT NULL,
    Student_ID INT NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #temp (Teacher_ID, Student_ID) VALUES 
    (123, 678),
    (123, 876),
    (123, 987),
    (456, 459),
    (456, 789);

--======================================

SELECT DISTINCT 
    UniqueID = x.ID
FROM 
    #temp t
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (t.Teacher_ID), (t.Student_ID) ) x (ID);
```

HTH,
Jason